# reversing an Ordering causes a compilation error

Tags: scala

I would like to define a reverse ordering for String pairs.
For some obscure reason, in the following code, the first line compiles (and I could use ord1.reverse later on) while the second line does not.

```
object Bug {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val ord1: Ordering[(String, String)] = Ordering.by(_._1)
    val ord2: Ordering[(String, String)] = Ordering.by(_._1).reverse
  }
}
```

What is wrong with this code? Why is it not okay to call .reverse here but ok later? What is the 'divergent implicit expansion'?

The errors I get in the repl:

```
<console>:10: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1._1)
       val ord2: Ordering[(String, String)] = Ordering.by(_._1).reverse
                                                          ^
<console>:10: error: diverging implicit expansion for type scala.math.Ordering[S]
starting with method Tuple9 in object Ordering
       val ord2: Ordering[(String, String)] = Ordering.by(_._1).reverse
                                                         ^
```

Edit: I found that writing this instead:

```
val ord2: Ordering[(String, String)] = Ordering.by((_: (String, String))._1).reverse
```

compiles, but it still does not make sense to me, plus the code is ugly as hell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limitation of the type inference of the Scala compiler. It cannot infer the type of this call:

```
def by[T, S](f: T => S)(implicit ord: Ordering[S]): Ordering[T]
```

Because you do not have a direct type ascription / return type but feed it into a second method `reverse`, even if that doesn't change the type parameter of the ordering.

The following would also work:

```
val ord2a = Ordering.by[(String, String), String](_._1).reverse
val ord2b = (Ordering.by(_._1): Ordering[(String, String)]).reverse
val ord2c = ord1.reverse
```